# Linking two jira issues, response

Tags: python, jira

I would like to link two jira issues, but want to make sure that they are not linked twice.
Is it even possible to double link issues in jira?
That is, if I do `jira.create_issue_link(type="Fixes", inwardIssue=issue1.key, outwardIssue=issue2.key)` on the same two issues that are already linked to `Fixes`, does this create a problem?
If so, how can I make sure / check, that there are no duplicate links?

I tried this, but it doesnt realy works

```
...
for issue1 in issues1:
    for issue2 in issues2:
        linked = False
        for link in jira.remote_links(issue2.key):
            if link.relationship in ["Fixes"] and link.object.key == issue1.key:
                linked = True
                print(f"1LINK_ISSUES: {issue2.key} is already linked with {issue1.key}")
                break
        if not linked:
            response = jira.create_issue_link(type="Fixes", inwardIssue=issue2.key, outwardIssue=issue1.key)
            print(f"{response}LINK_ISSUES: Linked {issue2.key} with {issue1.key}")
        else:
            print(f"2LINK_ISSUES: {issue2.key} is already linked with {issue1.key}")
...
```

I also tried this, in case there ist no problem with double linking:

```
...
for issue1 in issues1:
    for issue2 in issues2:
            response = jira.create_issue_link(type="Fixes", inwardIssue=issue2.key, outwardIssue=issue1.key)
            print(f"{response}LINK_ISSUES: Linked {issue2.key} with {issue1.key}")
...
```

response is always `<Response [201]>` - so i asked e, if there is an difference between in the response, between "two issues are already linked" and "new link between two issues was created"